# POST product with Shopify returns 406 error

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, shopify

```
        $url = "https://key:password@garageprints.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/products/product.json";
        $authentication = "key:password";
        $authentication = base64_encode($authentication);

        $postData = array(
            'product' => [
                'title' => 'Burton Custom Freestyle 151',
                'body_html' => 'Good snowboard!',
                'vendor' => 'Burton',
                'product_type' => 'Snowboard',
                'tags' => 'Barnes & Noble, John\'s Fav, Big Air'
            ]
        );

        $postData = json_encode($postData);

        // Setup cURL
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Basic ' . $authentication,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
        ));

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        return ($response);
```

Trying to send a post request with php code in Laravel returns an error. I know that it is not necessary to send the authentication through the header but I included it to show that I tried that. I am kinda new to curl with php so I am not very familiar with curl_setopt, I might be missing something obvious. I am using the example json file provided in Shopify api documentation.

Response in chrome, in the incoming connections Shopify returns a 200 code but the response variable being returned by php shows a [406 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moSj5.jpg)

Also I am sending the same request with postman but I only get the 200 ok status and a continue button with a link, yet sending the same request with PHP does not return this html file [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AovYL.png)

Comment: I don't see any issues myself, but I though I'd share that on Shopify's community they have staff who can answer and check the details of specific requests, so that might be helpful if no one else jumps on this. Noticed this while I was trying to find a solution for your issue.